# How can I access iCloud documents/files from an iOS device?

Tags: icloud

I completed a Numbers document on my Mac, saved to iCloud and now tried to open/read it on my iPhone 4S.

I can see it listed in *Settings → Manage Storage*, but how do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 5):

You can do so from the Numbers app on iOS. You don’t open it from manage storage. You open the app in which the document was created, on the iPhone.

Comment: Same thing goes for other file types such as Pages and Keynote.